# Duplicate VB.NET 'Like' operator behavior in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In the below samples, why is the first result (`x`) `True` and the second (`y`) `False`?

```
Dim x = "abc@symas-design.ch" Like "*symas-design.ch"
Dim y = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.LikeString("abc@symas-design.ch", "*symas-design.ch", CompareMethod.Text)
```

My goal is duplicating the behavior of VB.NET's `LIKE` operator in C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Like` operator apparently doesn't use `Operators.LikeString`, but instead `LikeOperator.LikeString`.

I tried this [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
Sub Main
    Dim x = "abc@symas-design.ch" Like "*symas-design.ch"
    Dim y = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.LikeString("abc@symas-design.ch", "*symas-design.ch", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text)

    x.Dump()
    y.Dump()
End Sub
```

And it showed:

```
True
False
```

So as you say, they are not the same. But then I showed the IL generated:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "abc@symas-design.ch"
IL_0005:  ldstr       "*symas-design.ch"
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.0
IL_000B:  call        Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LikeOperator.LikeString
IL_0010:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0011:  ldstr       "abc@symas-design.ch"
IL_0016:  ldstr       "*symas-design.ch"
IL_001B:  ldc.i4.1
IL_001C:  call        Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.LikeString
IL_0021:  stloc.1     // y
IL_0022:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0023:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
IL_0028:  pop
IL_0029:  ldloc.1     // y
IL_002A:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
```

It seems they're calling different methods, so then I tried this:

```
Sub Main
    Dim x = "abc@symas-design.ch" Like "*symas-design.ch"
    Dim y = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.LikeString("abc@symas-design.ch", "*symas-design.ch", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text)
    Dim z = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LikeOperator.LikeString("abc@symas-design.ch", "*symas-design.ch", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text)

    x.Dump()
    y.Dump()
    z.Dump()
End Sub
```

And I got:

```
True   <-- Like operator
False  <-- Operator.LikeString
True   <-- LikeOperator.LikeString
```

So you need to use `LikeOperator.LikeString` instead.

Here's a C# [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program to demonstrate:

```
void Main()
{
    bool z = LikeOperator.LikeString("abc@symas-design.ch", "*symas-design.ch", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text);
    z.Dump();
}
```

Which also outputs `True`.

Comment: Excellent answer!